# How to pass QSharedPointer<QObjectDerivedClass> to QML?

Tags: qt, qml

How can I pass an object of type QSharedPointer<QObjectDerivedClass> to QML?
If I do something like that

```
Q_PROPERTY(QObject* object READ object NOTIFY objectChanged)

public:
  QObject* object() { return m_object.data(); }
  void setObject(const QSharedPointer<QObjectDerivedClass>& object) { m_object = object; emit objectChanged(); }

signals:
  void objectChanged();

private:
  QSharedPointer<QObjectDerivedClass> m_object;
```

it works, but when I change the object with setObject() QML crashes randomly because the pointer holded by m_object is destroyed.
How can I fix it?

Comment: a) you shouldn't really have differences in the property type (`QObject *`) and WRITE method signature (`QSharedPointer<...>`). b) QML has own reference counting for QML-created objects, so you might get double-free problem if you create an object in QML and then store it into a smart pointer in C++.
What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: As for passing `QSharedPointer`s into-and-out-of QML, I don't think this is natively supported. You might want to wrap your shared pointer into either a `QVariant` or a C++ type exposed to QML and then use that instead.

Comment: The objects ownership is always Cpp, so there is not a double-free. The problem I'm trying to solve is the following: I need to have a class(call it Item) that exposes some properties, then, i need another class(call it Proxy) that exposes a QList<Item> as property, but if i use shared pointers I have some problems with memory management. If I use raw pointers (QList<QObject*>) the problem is solved but when should I delete them?

Comment: If `QList<Item>` always comes from C++ (so you don't have something like `listOfItems: [ Item {}, QtObject {} ]` in QML), then the dead-stupid Qt way would be to parent all your `QObject *` to the property owner of the `QList<QObject *>`. Then whenever that owner dies, your objects would automatically be destroyed. The reparenting is also possible afair.

Edit: [QObject::setParent()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#setParent) is a thing

Comment: Note that there's also [QQmlListProperty<T>](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmllistproperty.html) which can be used inside Q_PROPERTY to expose a list of objects to QML.